названия продуктов в художественной литературе
Вопрос по употреблению названия сыра в детской сказке.
Есть такие предложения:

Знаменитые сыроделы прислали только что изобретенный, совершенно странного вида, очень вкусный, интересный и дорогой сыр «Маасдам».
И весь дворец ликовал и смеялся, а маленькой мышке Аида отнесла на золотой тарелочке много кусочков чудного маасдама.
Существует легенда, что маасдам отправили в подарок русскому царю Петру Первому...
И с тех самых пор маасдам стал одним из самых уважаемых и дорогих сыров...

Верно ли оформлено название сыра? Я читала в справочниках, что в бытовом значении стоить писать со строчной буквы и без кавычек. Можно ли отнести детскую сказку к этому случаю. И стоит ли в первом предложении употреблять официальное название (кавычки, прописная буква)?


Я считаю, что в приведенных предложениях оформление верное.
Чтобы убедиться в этом, посмотрим перечень возможных форм написания.

Тематические группы имен собственных с разными формами написания
  Можно выделить 4 формы написания:
  Форма 1. Прописная буква, без кавычек (в специальной 
  литературе).
  Форма 2. Прописная буква с кавычками (основная форма).
  Форма 3. Строчная буква с кавычками.
  Форма 4. Строчная буква без кавычек.

Форма 3 и форма 4 фактически относятся к нарицательным существительным. Наличие кавычек в форме 3 говорит о том, что данное слово пока не считается общеизвестным термином (но в дальнейшем изменения возможны, нужен контроль по словарю). Также может учитываться стиль текста.

Можно посмотреть примеры в Карте слов: Предложения со словом «маасдам».

В данном случае  используются две формы, они же рекомендованы Розенталем в теме продуктов: Форма 2. Прописная буква с кавычками (основная форма). Форма 4. Строчная буква без кавычек.

В принципе форма 3 (строчная буква с кавычками) возможна,  но в данном тексте (по худ. стилю и неоднократности употребления слова) лучше писать без кавычек. В первом же предложении более официальный и торжественный вариант, где сыр как бы представляют читателю.


ПРИМЕРЫ
По пути она заглянула в коммерческий гастроном и купила сыр «Маасдам», с громадными дырками, масло и чёрный хлеб.
Марина Белякова, Стать архитектором!
Она любила весь сыр, но больше всего обожала маасдам.
Литературная магия Анны Старобинец, Глаза жирафа, или Война стихий

Я очень благодарна вам за столько подробное разъяснение. Теперь у меня не осталось сомнений и вопросов.
